# How to get the count of pass,fail,abandon test of build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Need count of pass/fail/abandon test of build pipelines, is there a way to do?
my python file:

```
    project = ""
    personal_access_token = ""
    pipeline_id = ""
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_date = end_date - relativedelta(weeks=1)
    start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization_encoded}/{project_encoded}/_apis/test/runs?$pipelineId={pipeline_id_encoded}&minLastUpdatedDate={start_date_str}&maxLastUpdatedDate={end_date_str}&api-version=6.0"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
        "Authorization": f"Basic {personal_access_token}"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        test_runs = response.json()
        for test_run in test_runs["value"]:
            print(f"Test Run ID: {test_run['id']}")
            print(f"Title: {test_run['name']}")
            print(f"Outcome: {test_run['outcome']}")
            print(f"Last Updated Date: {test_run['lastUpdated']}")
            print()
```

I am trying to do this way but its failing. It print the html Azure DevOps Services page on console.

I am getting this on console:

```
 <html lang="en-US">
    <head><title>
    
            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 

content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    
        <link data-bundlelength="516193" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M228_20230922.2/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vCZ9D6UIO_qlhG7RrGLDp5ecIS_cunZt7_o3iwWt7lrU=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M228_20230922.2/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-v-iQu887NdMc5JZJk3qLWWpoiugyfgcgvhjbmnbjhkWr3S8s=" rel="stylesheet" />
 href="/_static/tfs/M228_20230922.2/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vZeWfVvRTo2a7DO4ptMBi0cCBa3W_gjANgU36Es8paWQ=" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--UxServices customizations -->
    <link href="/_static/tfs/M228_20230922.2/_content/Authentication.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="platform"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireStart'); } 
require(["Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls","Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication"], function(){  if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireEnd'); } window.requiredModulesLoaded=true;  });  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with base64 also:

```
base64_token = base64.b64encode(f"{personal_access_token}".encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_token}"
}
```

And i am getting "failed to retrieve test runs error code 400". This way also its not working.
I updated my code this way:

```
credentials = ":" + pat
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()).decode()
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + token
}
test_outcomes = Counter()

        if test_results_response.status_code == 200:
            test_results = test_results_response.json()
            for test_result in test_results.get('value', []):
                outcome = test_result['outcome']
                test_case = test_result['testCase']['name']
                print(f'Test Case: {test_case}, Outcome: {outcome}')
                test_outcomes[test_case] += 1
    most_frequent_failed = test_outcomes.most_common(1)
    if most_frequent_failed:
        test_case, frequency = most_frequent_failed[0]
        print(f"Most Frequent Failed Test Case: {test_case} (Frequency: {frequency})")
    else:
        print("No failed test cases found.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve test runs. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

However if I am printing all outcome its diplaying non-stop list of passed test cases:

```
        if test_results_response.status_code == 200:
        test_results = test_results_response.json()
        for test_result in test_results.get('value', []):
            outcome = test_result['outcome']
            test_case = test_result['testCase']['name']
            print(f'Test Case: {test_case}, Outcome: {outcome}')
```

Comment: Where are you defining the variables `organization_encoded`, `project_encoded`, etc? Where are you encoding the PAT as base64? Did you look at the documentation for how to authenticate?

Comment: pipeline_id_encoded = quote(pipeline_id, safe='')
organization_encoded = quote(organization, safe='')
project_encoded = quote(project, safe='') thats what i tried because of errors. yes i do look for documentation and i tried as well but i am not able to figure it out. Kindly please suggest me what can be done. Thank you

Comment: Please do edits to your question, using [edit], because they look not so readable in a comment.   And (try to) explain something about "i tried because of errors" and "its failing". Remember no one can guess what error you see, as long as you do not share that info.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am still not sure whether I am on the right way doing it. If anyone have idea please help me

Comment: **Look at the documentation on authentication!** If something is unclear about the documentation, you can research it further or ask a question about it. The documentation explicitly tells you that you have to base64 encode your access token. Do you understand what base64 encoding is and how to do it? If not, start there.

Comment: I tried, nothing is working for me, if anyone knows other way to list all failed test cases of a pipeline, please let me know, will be thankful for any idea or suggestion

Comment: Please take a look at: [Pass rate trend of a test sample report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-test-analytics-pass-rate-trend-test?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)

Comment: @BuxiorEngineer You tried base64 encoding the access token? Where in your code are you doing that?

Comment: @DanielMann, yes i tried that too, base64_token = base64.b64encode(f":{personal_access_token}".encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8") and its not working also

Comment: "its not working also"..... Why not share the complete error message ?

Comment: @Luuk, i am getting 400 error code

Answer (score 0):

I can get the test result summary of a build with this [Resultsummarybypipeline - Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/resultsummarybypipeline/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2).

```
import requests
import base64
PAT = ''
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+PAT, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
response = requests.get(
    url="https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/testresults/resultsummarybypipeline?pipelineId={Pipeline_ID}&api-version=7.2-preview.1", headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

My test Result:

[image]